# Persistence unit is not persistent

Tags: java, jpa, hsqldb

I need persistence unit that creates embedded database which stays persistent after closing `EntityManager`.

This is my PU:

```
<persistence-unit name="hello-jpa" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
  <class>hello.jpa.User</class>
  <properties>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.format_sql" value="true"/>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.HSQLDialect"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="sa"/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:target/hsql.db"/>
    <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
  </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

And it deletes data after closing application.

Answer (score 3):

My understanding of [the documentation](http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/ch04.html) is that the "old" URL `jdbc:hsqldb:.` creates or connects to the same database as the new form for the URL `jdbc:hsqldb:mem:.` (i.e. in memory).

So try with the following URL instead: `jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/hsql.db`.

Comment: I doesn't work either :(. There is no such file lie target/hsql.db in both cases...

Comment: @etam Could you try with an absolute path (just to check)? I have a doubt about the working directory.

Comment: All I have is (with relative and absolute):

~/etam-svn/code/java/hello-jpa > ls target/
classes     hsql.db.log    maven-archiver
hello-jpa-derby-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar hsql.db.properties   test-classes

Comment: @etam I just did a test on my side and the following url `jdbc:hsqldb:file:target/testdb` definitely worked: ls target/
classes           test-classes  testdb.properties  xsd
surefire-reports  testdb.log    testdb.script

Comment: Does it persist objects between sessions?